# What is "Title, if not author" in copyright transfer form?

Tags: publications, copyright

In the ACM  [Copyright transfer form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQb5m.png) what is this "Title, if not author" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are the author, you should leave it blank.  If you are not the author, you should put your job title; presumably this would mostly explain why you are signing for the author.

Comment: In some organizations, researchers are not allowed to publish (and don't own the copyright to their papers) without the approval of the organization.